# AndroidでUSBシリアル通信を行うために、一般的に使用されるライブラリはありますか？

Tags: android, usb, シリアル通信

Android端末とデバイスをUSBで接続し、シリアル通信を行いたいです。(Androidがホスト)

Android APIリファレンスで探してみると、android.hardware.usbというクラスが見つかりました。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#java

Androidでの開発は初めてになるのですが、USB通信を行うためには、上記クラスを用いて
独自にクラスドライバを作成するのが一般的なのでしょうか？
例えば.NET FrameworkにおけるSerialPortクラスのような、気軽にUSB通信を行うことができるライブラリはないのでしょうか？
webで検索するとusb-serial-for-androidなど複数のライブラリが見つかりますが、信頼性が高いものはありますか？
https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

[開発環境]
OS: Windows10 Pro 64bit
IDE: Android Studio 3.2
言語: Java

(追記)
想定している構成図を添付します。[image: 構成図]

Comment: 少しわからないのですが、接続したいデバイスでは確実にシリアル通信ができる、ということでよろしいのでしょうか? 例えばPCにそのデバイスを接続した時にはシリアルポートとして認識され、ターミナルソフトをそのシリアルポートに接続して開くと、通信が可能になりますか?

Comment: >接続したいデバイスでは確実にシリアル通信ができる、ということでよろしいのでしょうか?　　その通りです。仮想COMを使ってPCと通信できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。だとしたらお調べになったドライバ含め、多くのドライバは対応しているはずです。英語の情報を含め少しばかり検索してみましたが、「一般的にこれを使うのが当たり前」と言うほど広く定着しているものはないように感じられました。情報が極端に少ないとか、公開直後でほとんどバグ取りされた形跡がないとかの一般的なふるいにかけられて、信頼性とかについてはご自身でサンプルプロジェクトを作って確かめてみられるしかないような気がします。リンクされたAndroidのUSB Host関連のAPIを概観してみましたが、USBプロトコルをかなり低レベルなところまで理解していないと、自分でドライバを作ると言うのは難しそうに見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。AndroidでUSB通信を行うこと自体があまりメジャーではないのかもしれませんね。有識者の意見をもう少し聞いてみたいですが、ご指摘の通り、信頼性については自己の判断に委ねられそうな気がします。

Answer (score 1):

普通、USBとシリアル通信の間を仲介する専用のICが使われており、そのICに対応したドライバを使います。

例えば、Future Technology Devices International（FTDI）社製のUSBシリアル変換チップは、よく見かけます。
そうしたよく使われるチップ用のドライバは、メーカーが提供している場合があるので自作しなくて済みます。

まず、どんなICが使われているのかを調べて、その型番と「ドライバ」でWeb検索してみると良いのではないかと思います。

Comment: 今回の場合、Android端末とデバイスの間に、変換機は用いません。質問に情報が不足していたようですみません。詳細な情報を追記いたします。

Comment: @nerik さん、変換機はクライアントのUSB-CDCデバイスの中に組み込まれています。そして大概はVID,PIDがその装置用にカスタマイズされています。装置自身のベンダがAndroid用のデバイスドライバを提供するか、Androidの中に既に組み込まれていれば、それが使えます。そうで無ければ質問に書かれたような第三者独自ドライバ/ライブラリを応用するしかありません。